# Is cyrillic actually missing in LinLibertine monospace?

Tags: luatex, fontspec, polyglossia, cyrillic

If you consider this MWE, then for me `lualatex` does *not* display `texttt{Привет, мир!}` but non-monospaced cyrillic text is displayed fine.

```
\documentclass[notitlepage,oneside]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\begin{document}
This text renders fine: Этот текст в порядке.

However, this does not: \texttt{Привет, мир!}
\end{document}
```

Adding `\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfonttt}{LinLibertine}` prints `texttt{Привет, мир!}` fine. Why do I need to specify `\newfontfamily` if `LinLibertine` appears to be capable of displaying cyrillic?

```
otfinfo -s /usr/share/fonts/OTF/LinLibertine_M.otf                                                   :(
DFLT        Default
cyrl        Cyrillic
grek        Greek
hebr        Hebrew
latn        Latin
latn.AZE    Latin/Azeri
latn.CRT    Latin/Crimean Tatar
latn.DEU    Latin/German
latn.MOL    Latin/Moldavian
latn.ROM    Latin/Romanian
latn.TRK    Latin/Turkish
```

Comment: Linux Libertine Mono has no Cyrillic glyph. Why it advertises being able to cope with that alphabet I don't know.

Comment: Here's the `fontforge` window where the Cyrillic glyphs are supposed to be http://i.stack.imgur.com/2oHov.png As you see, no glyph is shown.

Comment: Won't ``\usepackage{libertine}`` just load the 8-bit LaTeX fonts, whereas ``\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfonttt}{LinLibertine}`` loads the ``.otf`` font? In other words, just because the ``.otf`` font has Cyrillic glyphs, it doesn't mean the LaTeX font has as well.

Comment: @Sverre When {Xe|Lua}LaTeX is used, the `libertine` package switches to OpenType fonts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While `LinLibertine_M.otf` advertises covering `cyrl`, `grek` and `hebr`, it shows no glyph belonging to those alphabets.

Here is a picture of the font table obtained with `fontforge` and showing the Cyrillic range:

[image: Cyrillic]

No glyph is shown. With `otfinfo -g` the result is the same: no Cyrillic glyph name is output. So, yes: Linux Libertine Mono doesn't support Cyrillic.